# Target must not be null

Tags: android, get, androidhttpclient

Java code:

```
try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse =httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

where url is like:

```
http://122.180.133.121:84/diogo/api/api.php?class=authenticate&method=login_check&param={'userpassword':'777','username':'www'}
```

and logcat error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://122.170.103.168:86/diogo/api/api.php?class=authenticate&method=login_check&param={'userpassword':'123','username':'krunal'}
```

I already searched many solutions but all are saying about http or www.. but i dont know what is the actual problem. is just because of my server ip address or what.?

Comment: make sure its a valid url

Comment: i already checked it..its valid.

Comment: try encoding the url. a wild guess though

Comment: Check parameter names or encode your URL. using URL.encode()

Comment: @Raghunandan i already pass encoded url

Comment: @Prince its already encoded..

Comment: which type of encoding you user dear.

Comment: change url encoding method ,and try. it must be url ecoding problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change url encoding method. try this method. it must be **url encoding** problem-

> stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(urlString);

```
public static String stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(String input) {
    try {
        return stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(input, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "Java platforms are required to support UTF-8");
        // will never happen
    }
}

public static String stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(
        String input, String charset) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = input.getBytes(charset);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        int cp = bytes[i] < 0 ? bytes[i] + 256 : bytes[i];
        if (cp <= 0x20
                || cp >= 0x7F
                || (cp == 0x22 || cp == 0x25 || cp == 0x3C || cp == 0x3E
                        || cp == 0x20 || cp == 0x5B || cp == 0x5C
                        || cp == 0x5D || cp == 0x5E || cp == 0x60
                        || cp == 0x7b || cp == 0x7c || cp == 0x7d)) {
            sb.append(String.format("%%%02X", cp));
        } else {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: May be .. but in my case everytime it is encoding properly  :/

Answer (score 0):

[URIUtils.extractHost(final URI uri)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIUtils.html) can not get the target host because `param` contains illegal characters first located at index 88, `{`.

If you encode your complete URL with the default Java `URLEncoder` the resulting URL is

```
http%3A%2F%2F122.180.133.121%3A84%2Fdiogo%2Fapi%2Fapi.php%3Fclass%3Dauthenticate%26method%3Dlogin_check%26param%3D%7B%27userpassword%27%3A%27777%27%2C%27username%27%3A%27www%27%7D
```

but you can not use that URL because de default `URI` Java class can not parse it and obtain the scheme, host... etc

The solution, parse the illegal content only and pass to your URL parameter

```
String param = URLEncoder.encode("{'userpassword':'777','username':'www'}",
"UTF-8");

HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://122.180.133.121:84/diogo/api/api.php?
class=authenticate&method=login_check&param=" + param);
```